# Caliper giving 0 for all allocation metrics

Tags: java, gradle, benchmarking, caliper

The following benchmarking code in [Caliper](https://github.com/google/caliper)

```java
import com.google.caliper.BeforeExperiment;
import com.google.caliper.Benchmark;
import com.google.caliper.Param;
import com.google.caliper.runner.CaliperMain;

public class Bench_IsInstrumentationWorking {
    
    @Param({"1000"})
    private int size;

    private double[] array;
    
    @BeforeExperiment
    private void init(){
        array=new double[size];
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void bench(int reps){
        for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                array[j]=Math.random();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CaliperMain.main(Bench_IsInstrumentationWorking.class,args);
    }

}
```

results in 0 for all allocation metrics:

```java
Experiment selection: 
  Benchmark Methods:   [bench]
  Instruments:   [allocation, runtime]
  User parameters:   {size=[1000]}
  Target VMs:  [default@local]

This selection yields 2 experiments.
Trial Report (1 of 2):
  Experiment {instrument=allocation, benchmarkMethod=bench, target=default@local, parameters={size=1000}}
  Results:
    bytes(B): min=0.00, 1st qu.=0.00, median=0.00, mean=0.00, 3rd qu.=0.00, max=0.00
    objects: min=0.00, 1st qu.=0.00, median=0.00, mean=0.00, 3rd qu.=0.00, max=0.00
Trial Report (2 of 2):
  Experiment {instrument=runtime, benchmarkMethod=bench, target=default@local, parameters={size=1000}}
  Results:
    runtime(ns): min=17175.93, 1st qu.=17264.70, median=17345.48, mean=17403.70, 3rd qu.=17414.21, max=18080.08
Collected 27 measurements from:
  2 instrument(s)
  2 virtual machine(s)
  1 benchmark(s)

Execution complete: 19.28 s.
```

The `~/tmp/someNumber/trial-1.log` is riddled with

```java
Oct 05, 2021 5:53:26 AM com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenter instrument
[stderr] WARNING: Failed to instrument class.
[stderr] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 60
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:195)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:176)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:162)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenter.instrument(AllocationInstrumenter.java:192)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenter.instrument(AllocationInstrumenter.java:220)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenter.transform(AllocationInstrumenter.java:174)
[stderr]    at java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:244)
[stderr]    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
[stderr]    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:565)
[stderr]    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
[stderr]    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:168)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenter.bootstrap(AllocationInstrumenter.java:157)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenter.premain(AllocationInstrumenter.java:109)
[stderr]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[stderr]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[stderr]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[stderr]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[stderr]    at com.google.monitoring.runtime.instrumentation.AllocationInstrumenterBootstrap.premain(AllocationInstrumenterBootstrap.java:48)
[stderr]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[stderr]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
[stderr]    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[stderr]    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
[stderr]    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:515)
[stderr]
```

1. **Why is this and how to solve this?**

My guess is that the libs Caliper is using mayn't be suitable with JDK 16 (see environment details below). If so, what is the currently max. supported version it would run with?

*Further investigation has revealed that allocation stays 0 even when run on JDKs x.0.2 (11<=x<=14) but the log file shows no errors. On 15.0.2, behavior same as that on 16 and 17 (as above)*

---

**Env:**
Caliper: 1.0-beta-3
Gradle: 7.2
OpenJDK: 16.0.1
IDE: IntelliJ 2021.2.2 ,Community Edition
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'yourGroup.id'
version '0.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
//    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.caliper:caliper:1.0-beta-3'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Your hypothesis is plausible, but if Caliper has a version limitation, it's likely to have a _max_ version it would run with, not a min version.  The error definitely suggests you have the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

Google allocation doesn't support Java 16 or 17, since it has shaded copy of ASM in it that doesn't support these.

It needs Google allocation to be rebuilt with ASM 8 or 9